# Converting from int to char where overflow errors are concerned

Tags: c++, c++11

Isn't it a generally a bad idea to convert from a larger integral type to a smaller signed if there is any possibility that overflow errors could occur? I was surprised by this code in C++ Primer (17.5.2) demonstrating low-level IO operations:

```
int ch;

while((ch = cin.get()) != EOF)
    cout.put(ch); //overflow could occur here
```

Given that

- cin.get() converts the character it obtains to `unsigned char`, and then to `int`. So `ch` will be in the range `0-255` (exluding EOF). All is good.
- But then in the `put(ch)` expression `ch` gets converted back to `char`. If `char` is `signed` then any value of `ch` from `128-255` is going to cause an overflow, surely?

Would such code be generally bad practice if I'm expecting something outside of ordinary input `0-127`, since there are no guarantees how overflow is treated?

Comment: `cin.get` guarantees that if the return value isn't `EOF` then it's representable as `unsigned char`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I thought that was what I said. Maybe I should've been clearer, my concern is with the `cout.put(ch)` statement.

Comment: Ah, yes. As a rule, all the IO functions consider `char` values to be converted from `unsigned char`, so this is fine. Note that the conversion is *unspecified* and not "overflow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are rules for integer demotion.

> When a long integer is cast to a short, or a short is cast to a char,
>   the least-significant bytes are retained.

As seen in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eex498h.aspx

So the least significant byte of `ch` will be retained. All good.

Answer (score 0):

Use [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/), if you want to convert the integer into a null-terminated string which would represent it.

```
char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );
```

or you can convert it to a string , then char :

```
std::string tostr (int x){
    std::stringstream str;
    str << x;
    return str.str();}
```

convert string to char

```
string fname;
char *lname;
lname = new char[fname.lenght() + 1];
strcpy(f, lname.c_str());
```

if you see "Secure Error" disable it with #Pragma